# What did Omoc mean when he tried to explain the two points theory to Daniel?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the *Stargate SG-1* episode *[Enigma](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Enigma)*, Omoc, a Tallon, tries to explain to Daniel how two points can be far until brought together. He demonstrates this using a branch in its natural state, then bending it so the two points touch. Daniel responds with, "Oh. I learned this in freshman physics. You're talking about bending space." Omoc rebuts with, "No. You wouldn't understand."

So if Omoc wasn't talking about bending space-time or just space, then what theory could he have been referring to?

Comment: That's the joke. Daniel is talking about cutting edge human physics and Omoc just wand-waves that away.

Comment: @Richard: I'm not saying you are wrong (in fact: I'm sure you are right), but I don't know about 'cutting edge': General relativity is almost a hundred years old now. It might be cutting edge to the audience (and that's all it needs to be) but theoretical physics has more cutting edge stuff going today!

Comment: Your tiny human brain could not comprehend it.

Comment: @Einer While General Relatively is understood, putting it into practice - actually folding space isn't something humans have mastered. In this case, we rely on alien technology. Beyond cutting edge, from a certain point of view.

Answer (score 13):

In-universe, we learn that the Tollans claim to have "licked quantum physics", suggesting that their knowledge of physics goes well beyond our own conception of space-time and folded space.

Daniel's [interpretation](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouAreNotReady) of how their technology works prompts Omoc to smile, as you would if you heard a child explaining why the sky was blue.

> **Omoc:** *The distance between these two points seems far, until you do this.* (Omoc bends the branch ends together)
>   **Jackson:** *Oh I know this. One of our scientist talked about this. What you are talking about is folding space.*
>   **Omoc:** **(Smiling humorously)** *No, you wouldn't understand.*
>   **Jackson:** *I guess not. Let's hope the Nox do.*

Theoretically, the Tollans could be talking about using [multi-dimensional travel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_time_dimensions), [subspace travel](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Subspace), [hyperspacial travel](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Subspace) or even [parallel universe travel](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Alternate_reality) since all of these will appear in later episodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is in reference to relativity and our understanding of wormholes using relativity as a basis, but Omoc meant to say that relativity is a very basic and naive understanding of the universe and the Tollan know what's really going on in terms of physics (which apparently is not folding space).

Comment: Welcome to SF&S. This answer doesn't really say anything that isn't already in the question. Can you elaborate or offer some kind of justification?